# dlsym fails quietly loading from CoreTelephony

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, dll, core-telephony

I am trying to call a private function in the CoreTelephony framework; here is my current code:

```
double (*func)(void);

void *handle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);

if (!handle) {
    [@{@"handle": @"handle"} writeToFile:@"/var/mobile/err.plist" atomically:YES];
}

*(void **)(&func) = dlsym(handle, "CTRegistrationDataCounterGetLastResetTime");

if (dlerror() != NULL) {
    [@{@"symbol": @"symbol"} writeToFile:@"/var/mobile/err.plist" atomically:YES];
}

double r = (*func)();
NSNumber *a = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:r];
[@{@"time": a} writeToFile:@"/var/mobile/err.plist" atomically:YES];
dlclose(handle);
```

I know both the CoreTelephony binary and the `CTRegistrationDataCounterGetLastResetTime` symbol exist because if I insert gobbledegook for either I get an immediate crash. The code compiles fine, and no errors arise.

However, I don't think the function is getting called because it always returns 0, when it shouldn't (the `CTRegistrationDataCounterGetLastResetTime` function returns the date last time cellular data was reset in the number of seconds after 1 January 2001, GMT, hence it returning a `double`. The NSDate is gotten with `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:]`)

If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say something is wrong with my casting of the `void *` returned by `dlsym` to a function pointer. There seems to be a surprising amount of dispute over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to call that method, as I usually do, and really it returns 0, so I tried to call another method from CoreTelephony.

```
void *handle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_NOW);
if (!handle) {
    NSLog(@"Can't dlopen");
}

CFStringRef (*func)(CFAllocatorRef) = dlsym(handle, "CTRegistrationCopyLocalizedOperatorName");
if (dlerror() != NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Can't find symbol");
}

CFStringRef r = func(CFAllocatorGetDefault());
dlclose(handle);
```

And I got my operator name. So I think Apple just removed `CTRegistrationDataCounterGetLastResetTime` function.
[image]

Comment: I guess that was it: I succeeded with `CTRegistrationGetCellularDataIsEnabled` as well. I'm extremely surprised that `CTRegistrationDataCounterGetLastResetTime` returns garbage. I guessed wrong on that one.